# Find Lowest Common Ancestor Code Explanation

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking at the following code from Programming Interviews Exposed, and I can't seem to understand how exactly it works. Won't this method always return null?

```
// Overload it to handle nodes as well
Node findLowestCommonAncestor( Node root, Node child1,
                               Node child2 ){
    if( root == null || child1 == null || child2 == null ){
        return null;
    }

    return findLowestCommonAncestor( root, child1.getValue(),
                                     child2.getValue() );
}
```

Comment: If that's the exact code, then it will either return `null` or throw an exception when doing `getValue()` on one of the child nodes. What is won't do is `findLowestCommonAncestor`...

Comment: @Oded or stack-overflow due to infinite recursion.

Comment: @Jan - Unlikely, unless the tree is extremely deep (and chances are that if it is that deep, the application would hit an out of memory beforehand).

Comment: @Oded Who said it was a tree? You only know that `Node::getValue()` returns a `Node`.

Comment: @Jan - Node structures not in a tree?

Comment: @Oded I would expect `Node Node::getValue()` to `{return this;}`

Comment: Perhaps the method is supposed to be overridden by subcasses (see [call super](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super); even then, the code does not do much to actually `findLowestCommonAncestor`).

Comment: Do we know that getValue returns Node? Are there additional method signatures (overloads) of findLowestCommonAncestor, or is this snip of code all that is known?

Comment: There is an additional overload just before this one that takes in the values of each node instead of the nodes themselves. That one looks correct.

Comment: @hatchet Your comment is correct. I just realized the function call above is calling the overloaded method that is in the book just before this. If you want, provide it as an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippet, we don't really know what getValue returns. So if there are other overloaded versions of findLowestCommonAncestor, and getValue returns something other than Node, then the call to findLowestCommonAncestor in your snippet is not recursively calling itself.